No input file specified with apache configuration php-fpm redhat
I have a php 8 installation (php-fpm) with apache on a redhat server. The apache configuration contains this rule for php files in the virtualhost:
ProxyPassMatch ^(..php.)$  fcgi://X.X.X.X
The php-fpm pool contains doc_root and open_basedir configuration. It works well because any php file in the server is processed correctly
The problem:
When trying to access for example https://myurl.com/xxx/newfile.php/core/test.php I get "No input file specified" on the browser. It seems the test.php file is been searched and since it does not exists (it is just a path), I get an error.
Is there a configuration I should add to apache or php-fpm pool to allow that kind of url ? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
